# Why the result : "Compiz supported: no" with nvidia graphics card?

Tags: 14.04, unity, nvidia, compiz

I have been trying for a while to get a working Ubuntu system going in our house. I even had a computer built with the requirements listed on the Ubuntu website in mind. (But nothing new or fancy).

Despite numerous attempts I have had no luck getting a fully working system. On a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit, the system is slow. When I go to additional drivers and install the recommended driver (Nvidia-304) the system becomes unusable. Unity sort of starts but the icons are blurred. Although somethings are selectable they are very very slow and it would crash often. After much research I think this might be the most telling hint as to what is going on. After running the command (please note that as far as I can tell they is no VMware on my computer. I did an erase disk and install):

From `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -c -p`

I get the following results while still using the nouveau driver. I figured I might be able to figure out whats wrong from the beginning before changing things. If anyone has any suggestions or would like to see test results after installation of the driver please feel free to let me know.:

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc. 
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 128 bits) 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2

Not software rendered: no 
Not blacklisted: no 
GLX fbconfig: yes 
GLX texture from pixmap: yes 
GL npot or rect textures: yes

Compiz supported: no
```

Here is my result from `sudo lspci | grep VGA`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G72 [GeForce
7200 GS / 7300 SE] (rev a1)
```

Here are my results from sudo lshw -short :

```
H/W path Device Class Description
===================================================
                            system P35-S3G ()
/0 bus P35-S3G
/0/0 memory 128KiB BIOS
/0/4 processor Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E4600 @
/0/4/a memory 64KiB L1 cache
/0/4/b memory 2MiB L2 cache
/0/1b memory 2GiB System Memory
/0/1b/0 memory 1GiB DIMM 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
/0/1b/1 memory DIMM [empty]
/0/1b/2 memory 1GiB DIMM 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
/0/1b/3 memory DIMM [empty]
/0/100 bridge 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controlle
/0/100/1 bridge 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express PCI Express Ro
/0/100/1/0 display G72 [GeForce 7200 GS / 7300 SE]
/0/100/1a bus 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller
/0/100/1a.1 bus 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller
/0/100/1a.2 bus 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller
/0/100/1a.7 bus 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controlle
/0/100/1b multimedia 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller
/0/100/1c bridge 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1
/0/100/1c.4 bridge 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5
/0/100/1c.4/0 storage JMB368 IDE controller
/0/100/1c.5 bridge 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6
/0/100/1c.5/0 eth0 network RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Et
/0/100/1d bus 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller
/0/100/1d.1 bus 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller
/0/100/1d.2 bus 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller
/0/100/1d.7 bus 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controlle
/0/100/1e bridge 82801 PCI Bridge
/0/100/1f bridge 82801IB (ICH9) LPC Interface Controller
/0/100/1f.2 storage 82801IB (ICH9) 2 port SATA Controller [I
/0/100/1f.3 bus 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller
/0/100/1f.5 storage 82801I (ICH9 Family) 2 port SATA Control
/0/1 scsi0 storage
/0/1/0.0.0 /dev/cdrom disk DVDRAM GH20NS10
/0/2 scsi1 storage
/0/2/0.0.0 /dev/sda disk 250GB ST3250410AS
/0/2/0.0.0/1 /dev/sda1 volume 230GiB EXT4 volume
/0/2/0.0.0/2 /dev/sda2 volume 2045MiB Extended partition
/0/2/0.0.0/2/5 /dev/sda5 volume 2045MiB Linux swap / Solaris partition
/0/3 scsi2 storage
/0/3/0.0.0 /dev/sr1 disk DVD+-RW DH-16A6S
```

I have used Xfce with some success although I have had some problems. The thing is I got this machine so I would not have to do any workarounds. Is this a hardware problem? Would a different graphics card work? Which ones should I look for?

Comment: Well you picked a terrible video card that has had enough issues that it is blacklisted for unity/compiz. If you get a 8/9000 series card you may be able to run 14.04 (barely), assuming that you can use pci-e for a vid card.

Comment: Information that should be more readily available say on the recommended resources section of the Ubuntu site. Or did I miss a page? Thanks so much. I will chat with the guy who put it together. Thanks!

Comment: I agree - that page & a link out about gpu, (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DemystifyingUnityGraphicsHardwareRequirements) are quite outdated even though they show relatively recent edits. I'd get the best card that the system can handle & with-in your budget., I think people have been ok with 9000 series or even better. Maybe get some possible replacement 'names' & search here or Ubuntu forums first before commiting to buying, ect.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was that I have a lousy video card.

NVIDIA Corporation G72 [GeForce 7200 GS / 7300 SE] graphics card

Going to see if I can get an upgrade to my hardware.